# Parser Error (Javascript Beginner looking for solutions)

Tags: javascript

I'm new, so forgive my question if its somewhat banal. 
I received this error while learning Javascript:
SyntaxError: Parser error

Here's my code(I'm writing a simple Rock, Paper, Scissors Program):

```
var userChoice = prompt("Rock, Paper or Scissors?");
computerChoice = "null";

var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*1);
if (randomnumber <= (1/3)){
        computerChoice = "Rock";
    }
else if ((randomnumber > (1/3)) && (randomnumber <= (2/3))){
        computerChoice = "Paper";
    }
else {
    computerChoice = "Scissors";
}    
}
console.log(computerChoice);
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random()*1)` will **always** be `0`

Comment: Thanks, why is that? I thought it would take non-integer values between 0 and 1 and return something in that range instead of just zero.

Comment: A number between zero and one, multiplied by 1, is always a number between zero and one. When you pass that to `Math.floor()`, you'll always get 0.  The `Math.floor()` function always returns an integer; it's like `Math.round()` but it always rounds down.

Answer (score 1):

Give function name first with parenthesis , then always use syntax of if else which automatically create parenthesis pair, work in it.....so never you get error.

To find this type of error use firebug addons of firefox.. which tell you exact line no...(if single js you called else it give the appropriate code with line no.)

```
var userChoice = prompt("Rock, Paper or Scissors?");
computerChoice = "null";

var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*1);
if (randomnumber <= (1/3))
{
        computerChoice = "Rock";
}
else if ( (randomnumber > (1/3)) && (randomnumber <= (2/3)) )
{
        computerChoice = "Paper";
}
else {
    computerChoice = "Scissors";
}    
//} this is wrong.
console.log(computerChoice);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare `computerChoice` as a variable:

```
var computerChoice = null; //watch out "var"
```